# Настройка прокси-сервера на Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Приложение базируется на Xamarin. Как я могу настроить прокси-сервер для всего устройства Android? Есть приложение Drony, оно реализует его через что-то вроде VPN. Это какая-то библиотека или, может быть, функция в Android API? Я буду благодарен за любые советы о том, куда идти. Так как непонятно, с чего начать.

Comment: без прав рута проксю глобально указать не получится

Comment: @aepot получится, так работает приложение Drony (есть в PlayMarket)